# Memsql behavior if ram is completely used

Tags: database, singlestore

so currently I am trying to evaluate memsql as an option for database for our realtime pipeline.
I had one doubt, lets say we are using row-store for our tables and suddenly a burst of event comes in and we are not able to handle everything in memory.
Will it spill to disk or what behaviour will it show in such a scenario.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about queries consuming temporary memory, or write queries filling tables to memory capacity?

If queries are trying to consume more memory than is available, some queries will return an error. The client application can try them again later or schedule queries to avoid sending too large of a burst at the database.

If write queries are filling rowstore tables to memory capacity, they will start returning an error, and you will have to either expand memory capacity or delete some data. (Alternatively, you can consider using on-disk columnstore tables, depending on your workload.)

Comment: I am talking about insertion. Inserting data in tables, lets say from Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is "Does memsql store all rowstore data in memory"?

I too am doing a similar evaluation, and I cannot find the answer (yet) in the memsql documentation.

But based on my personal experience, it looks like ALL ROWSTORE tables ARE ONLY STORED IN MEMORY.  So if some of your leaf nodes run out of memory because of that, you are out of luck.  Write to COLUMNSTORE (well by then you might as well use ParAccel, Vertica, or Greenplum).

I thought memsql would be intelligent enough to store some of the rowstore data to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all rowstore data must fit into memory.  This is part of why MemSQL's rowstore is much faster then a traditional on-disk rowstore (see [MemSQL skiplist index](http://blog.memsql.com/the-story-behind-memsqls-skiplist-indexes/) for more details). The `maximum_table_memory` system variable controls how much memory MemSQL will allow in tables before it starts rejecting write queries (see [MemSQL memory management documentation](https://docs.memsql.com/v5.8/docs/memory-management).